# How to integrate openapi specifications from different APIs?

Tags: swagger, microservices, openapi

I wanted to ask if there is a way to aggregate in easy way OpenApi specifications from different APIs ?

We currently user Swagger for each of our APIs and there we added custom logic to authenticate, we also add rules for different rules for accessibility.

However it would be much more convenient to somehow aggregate all of those APIs and keep the authentication, access logic in the same place.

**Example:**

We have two separate microservices with separate APIs and separate addresses

API 1 localhost:5000

- Separate project with Orders API
- Separate swagger accessible under this url

API 2 url localhost:5001

- Separate project with Notifications API
- Separate swagger accessible under this url

**The end result we want:**

Some kind of aggregation framework or sample project that would be able to pull Open API specification generated by Swagger of those projects and basically show it as one under some new url under

url localhost:5002

- We get aggregated Swagger or some other framework showing endpoints from Orders API and Notifications API

Basically I would assume this problem would be common among people using microservices that need to provide to the clients some kind of Public API specification from multiple microservices. In most cases client would like to see it as one

Comment: Could you add some examples? It's not super clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @DMalan I added an example. Sory for not being clear. I try my best to describe the problem at hand :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, proposed scenario is:

- Merge your doc.xml files
- Then convert XMLs to YAML (example in this way https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-yaml)
- Then convert YAML to Swagger preview (example in this way https://editor.swagger.io)

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to ask if there is a way to aggregate in easy way OpenApi specifications from different APIs ?

You can use APIMatic's API spec merge feature to first [merge your specs](https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#merging-two-api-specifications---a-basic-example) and then [transform](https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#transforming-the-zipped-file) the merged output into OpenAPI's format. Here are the steps:

1. Structure your directory as follows:

```
dir\
  api1\  
    openapi.json
  api2\
    openapi.json
  APIMATIC-META.json
```

2. A minimalistic `APIMATIC-META.json` can look like this to enable merging:

```
{
    "MergeConfiguration": {
        "MergedApiName": "Public API",
        "MergeApis": true,
        "MergeSettings": {
          "SkipCodeGenValidation": true
       }
    }
}
```

3. ZIP the directory, upload it and transform it via their website to OpenAPI v3 to get your merged/aggregated OpenAPI output. Here is a link that provides step by step guide on uploading and performing a transformation: https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#transforming-the-zipped-file

If you are looking to automate the process, APIMatic has an API too: https://www.apimatic.io/docs/api#/http/api-endpoints/transformation/transform-via-file

You can also check out details for generating a unified portal/docs for your merged API spec here: https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/ . This particular [section](https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#post-processing-the-merged-output) here talks about the ability to override information like server URLs etc.